# Connotation of the phrase "bidding big"

Tags: connotation, collocation, is-it-a-phrase

Is it correct to say that a bid is "big"? What connotations does the phrase *bidding big* come to the average native speaker's mind?

Is the phrase, "bidding big" positive or negative? Is it daring or stupid? Is it powerful or weak?

**More information:** Some people mentioned that my question suffer from lack of context. Here is the context: I want to start a real estate business and I am not sure whether the name **Big Bid** is the right name? I am thinking maybe it defeat the purpose. People might say they are not looking for someone who bid big, for example, because it is "stupid" and it might be more reasonable to bid **small** first and go with the flow.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but there are too many questions combined in this post. To answer (4), unless we're talking to somebody who speaks a different dialect of English (New Zealanders come to mind), we don't usually confuse *bid, bead, bed*, and *bad*.

Comment: I haven't heard this idiom --  ***context would help tremendously*** -- but I'd interpret it as having the same connotations as "bidding high". Which can be either of any of the attributes you ask about, depending on ***context***.

Comment: I looked at the previous versions of your original question. It seems you were mostly confused by the **pronunciation** of the letter **i** in the two words *big* and *bid* placed together. You argued that the expression sounded more like **big bed** Is that still true for you?

Comment: Unless you can quote where you saw the expression *bidding big*, it's a futile exercise for anyone to answer your question. "He is/they are bidding big ...." is not idiomatic.

Comment: In the context of a _call for tenders_, often big is not good.

Comment: It's just as well you put a bounty on this question, because asking whether a name for a business is **suitable** is off topic on EL&U as you are asking for an opinion. BUT, because you mention that the business you want to set up is a real estate one, perhaps your question has some language relevancy.

Comment: Typo: **soomeine**  I think you mean SOMEONE. Please check your spelling before posting, spell checkers are free and you can install an English dictionary spell checker on any browser. When a spelling error occurs a red wavy line will appear. Spell checkers are not infallible but they will pick up on typos, unless the typo is also a proper word.

Comment: The context needed is where you have encountered the expression and how often. If the answer to the first question is 'never', you shouldn't be posting your question. Some research is required on ELU.

Comment: "Bid Big" is a terrible name for a real estate business. First of all, it doesn't make complete sense. What are you bidding on? Sometimes realtors bid on properties, but not always. Secondly, people selling property want you to sell high, but people buying want to buy low. "Bid Big" makes me think you're going to opt for higher prices on lots of things and I probably want you to play it safe and smart and not just "Bid Big" whatever that means for my situation

Comment: The added context actually make the question off-topic. This is opinion-based at best!!

Comment: Sorry about the spelling mistake. Thank you @L_LV for the explanation. Like you said I just needed to know about the connotation of the phrase.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment sounded harsh, critical or "worked up". It was above all a tip, a suggestion, a piece of advice. Take it or leave it. I often edit posts when I believe the poster has disappeared or there are so many errors it's just quicker to fix most of them myself. When I see a poster *does* edit his/her own post I leave a comment telling them they missed something, sometimes it's just a typo. Usually as soon as the typo has been fixed I delete my comment.

Comment: I was also *unsure* what the exact word might be, hence I wrote "I think". The caps was meant to stand out so the OP would immediately notice it among the many comments left by users. I can see how that might be interpreted in the wrong spirit. Actually, I've just remembered. I *did* edit your post because there were a number of errors. Your "more information" edit came after mine, hence I didn't want to be seen as someone who was meddling.

Comment: @J_LV please see my comments above. Thanks. If the question seems otherwise fine, there's a reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be positive or negative depending on context, daring or stupid depending on context. *Big bid* on its own doesn't have any connotation.

However you could say it's *powerful* in the sense that it always involves a large amount of money, goods or whatever else you may bid with.

> He made a big bid on that car!

works just fine.

And as there seems to be an ongoing discussion about whether or not "bidding  big" can be used:

> Chinese bidding big at home auctions

This quote is from the [New Zealand Herald](http://www.nzherald.co.nz/business/news/article.cfm?c_id=3&objectid=10848593).

> NetFlix is bidding big on new original series The Crown, which could cost more than House Of Cards

This one is from [TechCrunch](http://techcrunch.com/2014/05/22/netflix-the-crown/?ncid=rss&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20Techcrunch%20%28TechCrunch%29).

And even though it's true that you usually bid on things that have a price and that *high* should be used when referring to a price *level*, ***big*** is the correct adjective to use in reference to the **volume** of a bid.

**Regarding your edit:**

As Mari-Lou A pointed out, I doubt you will find an objective way of telling whether that's a name you should use for your company or not, as that's entirely opinion-based. However, keep in mind that a company named "Big Bid" certainly is unlikely to attract someone looking for low-end/affordable real estate.

"Big Bid" as a company name somewhat implies that you're offering/involved with high-end real estate rather than mid to low-end real estate. That's because *big bid* implies a certain willingness to spend a larger amount of money. Therefore, a customer who doesn't like that idea will assume you got nothing to offer in his (lower) price range.

Regardless of that I would not use that name, even for a high-end real estate company. To me, it seems like a bad choice, especially for a company that has yet to grow. But then again, I have no clue what your mission statement is and what kind of customers you're trying to attract.

Comment: The 'bidding big' of Netfix actualy means 'making a big bet'.

Comment: Your citation is interesting, but I still think that the expression 'bidding big' carries the connotation of 'bet'. This  is actually an intresting point about its usage.

Comment: @Josh61 It doesn't to me. And after having fully read the NetFlix article I just removed - it didn't there either. I assumed you were correct and did not want to mislead but in the article I removed _bidding big_ is used in reference to "Netflix has been investing heavily in new original content". It doesn't carry the connotation of making a wager but was used to describe that NetFlix is bidding big on The Crown in the hopes of making it their next original series.

Comment: Let's see what other users think about it! :))

Comment: I would agree with both of you;  *investing heavily* seems a near-synonym of *placing a large bet*.

Comment: @TimLymington I'd argue that this entirely depends on the nature of the investment. An investment per se is defined as _the outlay of money, usually for income or profit_. The term "investment" does not imply **any** level of risk or uncertainty, but merely describes the act of committing your money to something. A bet however means _something staked on an uncertain outcome_.

Comment: In _bidding high_, _high_ is probably more adverbial than adjectival. (The example I've seen discussed is _shoot wide_. Is the modifier addressing the action or the final state? Who can say?)

Answer (score 3):

In the context of making an investment, *to bid* can mean either of two things:

1) To make a fixed offer (for instance, in the case of a takeover bid).

2) To take part in an auction, competing against other bidders who successively raise the price they say they are willing to pay until no more offers are made.

'To bid big' therefore means 'to offer a high price', either making an independent offer (sense 1) or in the context of an auction (sense 2).

Whether this connotation is desirable for a real estate company will depend on the quality of the properties it is handling (and probably how fashionable the area is in which those properties are located), and the type of buyer it is targeting.

It might be fine if your prospective clients have money to burn; but not if they are in the middle-to-low income range. Maybe you should have some focus-group testing done by a marketing company...